# How can I find all packages from WAB in osgi container?

Tags: java, maven, wab

I have written one WAB bundle and deployed in an osgi container. In this WAB bundle, I have exported one package say `"com.company.b2b.test.framework"`.
Now I have written a simple osgi bundle which has dependency on WAB bundle. I have imported `"com.company.b2b.test.framework"` package by making an entry in `pom.xml` file, and wrote on one java class which use few classes from this package. The build is failing in eclipse with below error:

```
package com.company.b2b.test.framework does not exist
```

The package structure of WAB bundle is provided below:

```
company.b2b.test-framework-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      |
      |__META-INF
      |
      |__OSGI-INF
      |
      |__WEB-INF
              |
              |__classes
                    |
                    |__com
                         |
                         |__company
                                |
                                |__b2b --> test --> framework
```

In wab bundle, we see all classes are actually under `WEB-INF/classes/ directory`, and that is the reason, other simple bundle is not able to find the required package.
Can anybody suggest me how to export the package `"com.company.b2b.test.framework"` so that any other bundles can access this package directly?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? Same problem here